# CSS selector - element with a given child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm looking to make a selector which will select all elements if they have a specific child element. For example, select all `<div>` with a child `<span>`.

Possible?

Comment: Given Jeff's [recent comments on dupes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) I'm not voting to close as a duplicate, however it's worth pointing out that there are quite a few other questions here on SO that [discuss the much-desired parent-selectors](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22parent+selectors%22+css+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Why does Google persistently bring me to SO 'duplicate' answers right at the top of the results ranking, rather than the one to which they all refer?
search: 'css select parent with specific child' yields SO results: 1:4220327 2:14509590 3:11547535;  the given existing answer 1014861 is not on the first page.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

> Is it possible to select an element if it contains a specific child element?

Unfortunately not yet.

The [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) and [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/#selectors) selector specifications do not allow for any sort of parent selection.

---

#### A Note About Specification Changes

This is a disclaimer about the accuracy of this post from this point onward. Parent selectors in CSS have been discussed for many years. As no consensus has been found, changes keep happening. I will attempt to keep this answer up-to-date, however be aware that *there may be inaccuracies due to changes in the specifications*.

---

An older ["Selectors Level 4 Working Draft"](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) described a feature which was the ability to specify the ["subject" of a selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject). **This feature has been dropped and will not be available for CSS implementations**.

The subject was going to be the element in the selector chain that would have styles applied to it.

<sub>Example HTML</sub>

```
<p><span>lorem</span> ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>consecteture edipsing elit</p>
```

This selector would style the `span` element

```
p span {
    color: red;
}
```

This selector would style the `p` element

```
!p span {
    color: red;
}
```

---

A more recent ["Selectors Level 4 Editor’s Draft"](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) includes "The Relational Pseudo-class: `:has()`"

`:has()` would allow an author to select an element based on its contents. My understanding is it was chosen to provide compatibility with [jQuery's custom `:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-selector*.

In any event, continuing the example from above, to select the `p` element that contains a `span` one could use:

```
p:has(span) {
    color: red;
}
```

---

<sub>* This makes me wonder if jQuery had implemented selector subjects whether subjects would have remained in the specification.</sub>

Comment: great answer... also consider this reading https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: CSS is a great tool and javascript should be avoided for these purposes. However, this is a great example why developers accept other means to an end in order to achieve what they want. Too bad...

Comment: :has is great but well supported http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas

Comment: @PaulLedger Did you mean great but NOT well supported? I'd say not supported at all in CSS.

Comment: @dgtlife
It is now supported in the latest versions of safari.

Comment: Now also firefox seems to have it by default since version 121.

Answer (score 151):

**Update January 2023 - Only IE is not supporting `has()`**

The [`:has()` pseudo-selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo) from the CSS Selectors 4 spec addresses this use case.

To use it, we will write something like:

```
.foo > .bar:has(> .baz) { /* style here */ }
```

In a structure like:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    <div class="baz">Baz!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This CSS will target the `.bar` div - because it *both* has a *parent* `.foo` and from its position in the DOM, `> .baz` resolves to a valid element target.

---

**Original Answer** (left for historical purposes) - *this portion is no longer accurate*

For completeness, I wanted to point out that in the [Selectors 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) specification (currently in proposal), this will become possible. Specifically, we will gain [Subject Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#subject), which will be used in the following format:

```
!div > span { /* style here */
```

The `!` before the `div` selector indicates that it is the element to be styled, rather than the `span`. Unfortunately, no modern browsers (as of the time of this posting) have implemented this as part of their CSS support. There is, however, support via [a JavaScript library called Sel](https://github.com/amccollum/sel), if you want to go down the path of exploration further.

Comment: as of August 2022 Chrome 105 supports `:has` as well. Firefox 103 is not yet ready but progress is tracked in [bug #418039](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=418039).

Answer (score 60):

I agree that it is not possible in general.

The only thing CSS3 can do (which helped in my case) is to select elements that have no children:

```
table td:empty
{
   background-color: white;
}
```

Or have any children (including text):

```
table td:not(:empty)
{
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: ONly :not(:empty) works for me. Solely :empty not working

Comment: empty only works if it has nothing in it, not a character at all...