# CSS unknown number of intermediate elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a DOM tree which looks something like this (formulated as a regex):

```
div.container (div.notbox | div.box)+
```

Now I need so select all "first-level" .box children. Lets assume following document:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="box" id="1">
            <div class="box" id="2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="3"></div>
</div>
```

In this case I would need to select #1 and #3, but not #2.
Is there a way to formulate that with a CSS query? Something like

```
.container > :not(.box) > .box
```

but repeat the :not(.box) clause an indefinite amount of times?

Comment: PS: if someone knows a better name for the question; I'm open for suggestions

Comment: Trying to understand your goal: are you trying to select all .box elements which are not themselves a child of a .box?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4220347/1132354

Comment: @DanielBeck exactly!

Comment: Yeah, as nikhil points out this is one of those things that is Harder Than It Should Be.  Depending on the styling I might just do `.box {/* do stuff */}` and `.box .box {/* undo that stuff */}`

Comment: A bit of recursive jQuery could probably do the trick. I'm not sure what you want to do is possible without javascript though.

Comment: I think you should just update your markup in order to make it (a lot) easier to target with your css. You're using same class for 3 different levels and CSS isn't powerful enough to satisfy what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this way:

```
.box {/* styles */}
.box .box {/* styles */}
```

Anyway I'd suddgest you to create different classes:

```
<div class="container">
<div>
    <div class="box" id="1">
        <div class="childBox" id="2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="3"></div>
```

Or if same styles needed plus a childBox styles :

```
<div class="container">
<div>
    <div class="box" id="1">
        <div class="box childBox" id="2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="3"></div>
```