# Show/hide links with CSS based on radiobutton selection

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show/hide hyperlinks according to the currently checked radiobutton. This is working until I wrap the radiobuttons inside `<ul><li>` elements.

**CSS**

```
.site {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out, height .5s ease-in-out,background  .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out, height .5s ease-in-out,background  .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out, height .5s ease-in-out,background  .5s ease-in-out;
}
input[id=rbSites]:checked ~.site {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 15px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" id="rbSites" name="types"> 
<label for="supportCase">Sites</label>
<input type="radio" id="rbOther" name="types"> 
<label for="other">Other</label>
<div class="cell site">Link to</div>
<a class="site">SiteX</a>
<a class="site">SiteY</a>
<a class="moblie">AppX</a>
```

The above stops working as soon as the radiobuttons are wrapped inside `<ul><li>` elements, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="rbSites" name="types"> 
    <label for="supportCase">Sites</label>
    <input type="radio" id="rbOther" name="types"> 
    <label for="other">Other</label>
  </li>
<ul>
```

See [jsFiddle without `<ul><li>`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzv4v6aq/) and [with `<ul><li>`](https://jsfiddle.net/vr8r9r8k/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.site` is no longer a sibling, so the `~.site` selector doesn't work once the radiobutton has been wrapped inside `<ul><li>`.

You would need an additional parent selector (to select the `<ul>` and then `~.site`) or a method to select an element (`<ul>`) with a certain childelement (the checked radiobutton).

Unfortunately, I'm afraid both options will only be available in CSS4. Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/1300910) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4220347/1300910) answer.