# How to apply css to outer div if ul item contains li items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have two cases in my rendered HTML page.

**Case 1:**

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul> 
<div class="test">Testing here</div>
```

**Case 2:**

```
<ul></ul>
<div class="test"></div>
```

In case 1, I want to apply **`CSS`** to the `div` if `ul` element contains `li` elements). I don't want anything for case 2. I want a pure CSS approach without any jQuery/JavaScript.

Comment: It's impossible with this version of CSS (maybe with css4) you can achieve this by using JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector - element with a given child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220327/css-selector-element-with-a-given-child)

Comment: _I want to apply a class to the div_ What is that mean?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt :Means apply style to class test in case one only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to **[UncaughtTypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5283476/uncaughttypeerror)**'s answer.

There is a selector `:not(:empty)` for applying css to element if it has a child.

Check the [:not(:empty)](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/css-not-empty-selectors/) for more details about the selector.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul:not(:empty) + .test {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul> 
<div class="test">Testing here</div>

<ul></ul>
<div class="test">Testing here</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The intended behaviour can be achieved with the use of the *[Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)* (`+`) and the `:empty`<sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)</sup> *pseudo-class*, e.g:

```
ul:empty + .test
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul:empty + .test {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul> 
<div class="test">Testing here</div>

<ul></ul>
<div class="test">Testing here</div>
```

1. > The **adjacent sibling combinator** (`+`) separates two selectors and
   >   matches the second element only if it *immediately* follows the first
   >   element, and both are children of the same parent element.
   >   <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)</sup>
2. > The **:empty** CSS [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) represents any element that has no
   >   children. Children can be either element nodes or text (including
   >   whitespace). Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether
   >   an element is considered empty or not. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)</sup>