# Apply style to last-child of parent, only if particular child exists

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors

I've got some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The `child` may or may not be rendered in the html, the `parent` will always be rendered.  I've got CSS like this:

```
  .parent {
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  .parent:last-child {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
```

This isn't working quite right.  I'd like to apply `page-break-after: always;` only on `parent`s that have a `child` and `page-break-after: avoid;` to the last parent with a `child` element.  So for example, if the html is rendered like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    MISSING
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The `page-break-after: always;` should go on the first and third `parent`, and the `page-break-after: avoid` should go on the last `parent`.

If it looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    MISSING
</div>
```

The `page-break-after: always;` should go on the first and second `parent`, and the `page-break-after: avoid` should go on the second `parent`.

Is there a way to do this with CSS selectors?  It's important that this works correctly in MS Edge and IE 11 browsers.  I'm using Angular 6, if that matters.

Comment: If the template markup includes loops and/or conditions, can we see it?

Comment: Not in css for now, but maybe in the future https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has even SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220327/css-selector-element-with-a-given-child

Comment: @ConnorsFan it does not contain loops.  The conditions are on the child elements.

Comment: It may be possible to get it working with Angular style binding.