# Using a::after for links in text but exclude linked images

Tags: css

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q8dtrkzL/)

I'm using

```
a::after {
  content: " »";
}
```

to style links. It works:

```
<a href="#">Some linked Text</a>
```

Sadly I now get a „»“ after linked images, what I don't want that:

```
<a href="#"><img src="test.jpg"></a>
```

What do I have to change in order to get „»“ after linked words, but not after linked images?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector - element with a given child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220327/css-selector-element-with-a-given-child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to hide the symbol under the image using negative margin:

```css
a::after {
  content: " »";
}
a img {
  margin-right:-13px;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Some linked Text</a> </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?image=0"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works for me, but it's a pitty, that there is no CSS selector for element with a given child

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your problem, but if you only want the simbol in texts, you can use classes to delimit it.

```css
.text::after {
  content: " »";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="text">Some linked Text</a> 
<br><br>

<a href="#" class="img"><img src="test.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:has` pseudo-class

```
a:after {
    content: " »";
}
a:has(img):after {
    content: '';
}
```