# How to find parent of two elements that match CssSelectors?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given the following (generic) dynamic HTML structure:

```
<ol id="myOrderedList">
    <li id="someGuidICantPredict">
        <span data-serial="someData1">someData1</span>
        <span data-manufacturer="someDataB1">someDataB1</span>
    </li>
    //(repeated many times with different data)
</ol>
```

How do I find the following:

Find the `<li>` where the spans match by CssSelector for both `data-serial` and `data-manufacturer`?

I know how to do this for one or the other span tag thusly:

```
By.CssSelector($"#olCurrentTanks li span[data-serial={serial1}]")
```

or

```
By.CssSelector($"#olCurrentTanks li span[data-manufacturer={manufacturer1}]")
```

But I don't know how to find the parent `<li>` element where *both* spans match. Meaning I need to get the `IWebElement listItem` where the both span's data attributes match the corresponding data which I *can* predict.

Edit: Difficulty: Okay to use x-path to get the `li` parent but not to find the spans.

Comment: Look here, css doesn't have the capability to look up element based on its children elements - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220327/css-selector-element-with-a-given-child. Even in your sample where you successfully matched based on one element, you were matching the `span`, not the `li` you were after. xpath is the way to go for anything more complex in the DOM.

Comment: Are you trying to say that "CSS can't find a parent"? Because that's certainly true. But we're not 100% working in CSS. We're working with what amounts to a modified query selector format that can include all kinds of interesting things because it's selenium :)

Comment: :) yes, and xpath has a solid place in my heart at least  :) I was just commenting re: your original intent, to accomplish that with a css, not really possible.

Comment: I was trying to limit xpath simply because if I wrap those controls in, say, a div, the xpath changes and my tests break. The less fragile it is, the happier I am :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) you can get `li` element with specific `span`s children:

```
//li[./span[@data-serial="someData1"] and ./span[@data-manufacturer="someDataB1"]]
```

Selector below will give all `li` elements as a list for `FindElements` and single first one for `FindElement`:

```
By.XPath("//li[./span[@data-serial='someData1'] and ./span[@data-manufacturer='someDataB1']]")
```

Code examples:

```
IList<IWebElement> allMyLi = driver.FindElements(By.XPath($"//li[./span[@data-serial='{serial1}'] and ./span[@data-manufacturer='{manufacturer1}']]"));

foreach (var myLi in allMyLi)
{
    IWebElement serial = myLi.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"span[data-serial={serial1}]"));
    IWebElement manufacturer = myLi.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"span[data-manufacturer={manufacturer1}]"));

    Console.WriteLine("serial, manufacturer: {0}, {1}", serial.Text, manufacturer.Text);
}
```

Comment: As long as the Xpath doesn't require other DOM structures except the ol and li, this *might* work. But I need to know how to do a By.XPath("xpath1 && xpath2") because the By.XPath parameter is a single string. Or is that literally the string?

Comment: why you need `xpath1 && xpath2`? what is your goal, can you clarify.

Comment: This was what I was looking for: By.XPath($"//li[./span[@data-serial='{serialNumber}'] and ./span[@data-manufacturer='{manufacturer}']]")

Your answer got me there so I'm calling it as the right one. 

The reason I need it this way is that the list items are inside a jquery ui selectable with a remove feature. I need to check to see if the item that was removed is actually gone. The only way to predictably check that is for the serial number AND manufacturer spans to be gone along with parent list item as both count as a complex primary key. Thank you!