# Target div only if specific child tag does not exist

Tags: css

I have these two examples:

```
<div class="hello">
    <figure> text </figure>
</div>

<div class="hello">
    <figure> text </figure>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
</div>
```

Via CSS, is it possible to target the `hello` div **only** if it does *not* contain the `<figcaption>` tag?

So with the above example, I want to target the first `hello` div...

Comment: No, not with CSS alone unfortunately.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4220347/9325419)