# Apply :not in nested table

Tags: html, css

```css
table.parent td:nth-of-type(1):not(table.nested td){
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<table class="table parent">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXTA</td>
    <td>TEXTB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Has nested table below
        <table class="table nested">
        <tbody>
        <thead>
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>TEXTC</td>
    <td>TEXTD</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have a nested table as follows -

```
<table class="table parent">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXTA</td>
    <td>TEXTB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Has nested table below
        <table class="table nested">
        <tbody>
        <thead>
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>TEXTC</td>
    <td>TEXTD</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Requirement - Only TEXTA and TEXTB should be colored in red. In real scenario there are many rows. I want only the first td of each row in the parent table to be colored. I am doing something like -

```
table.parent td:nth-of-type(1):not(table.nested td){
  color: red; 
}
```

This is not giving me any result. What is the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data. And it's very seldom when nested tables are really necessary. I believe your case is not exception. HTML5 provides sufficient quantity of elements to layout documents.  See also [w3c recomedations](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.1)

Answer (score 1):

Spent a while playing around with this. The best I can do is to suggest using 2 lines of CSS rather than 1. One selector to do all of the first row of `td` and one to set the `nested` ones back to how they belong.

```css
table.parent tr:first-child td {
  color: red; 
}

table.nested tr:first-child td {
  color: black; 
}
```

```html
<table class="table parent">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXTA</td>
    <td>TEXTB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Has nested table below
        <table class="table nested">
        <tbody>
        <thead>
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>TEXTC</td>
    <td>TEXTD</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: the reason I didn't  use this method is because in real scenario there are other styles also which I am applying . These too get inherited. While this fix works for color property, it fails for opacity. ( I don't understand why). For example, if I apply 70% opacity in table.parent td:first-child{} , it gets reflected in the table too which I am just not able to change back to 100% .  Isn't there any direct way to achieve this without having to apply and reapply css?

Comment: @ItykaBandta I think opacity is a unique one since you can not have the parent be like `opacity: 0.5` but the child to be `opacity: 1`. This is avoided by using `rgba()` for `background-color` but otherwise I am not sure. 
Sadly I could not find a way to do what you are asking with 1 line of CSS

Comment: Makes sense. I am thinking if I could handle this scenario using scripting. Like we have .has() to filter out elements. So, let's say I want to add background only to the td which contains nested table, I would write something like $( "td" ).has( "table" ).css( "background-color", "red" ); and it works. Is there anything opposite of :has in jquery or JS? That would solve the problem.

Comment: @ItykaBandta I am not sure, as I am not expert with JS or Jquery. I would repost this question, but asking for a JS or Jquery answer.

Answer (score 1):

You said that..

> I want only the first td of each row in the parent table to be colored

So, I am assuming you want TEXTA and `TEXTC` to be colored (and not `TEXTB` as you stated).

If thats the case, then your idea was to select elements (first td of each row) if they dont contain `a specific child element` (table.nested).

This is not possible with CSS2 or CSS3.

The CSS2 and CSS3 selector specifications do `not` allow for any sort of `parent selection`.

See [CSS selector - element with a given child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220327/css-selector-element-with-a-given-child)

**Edit**

You can use jquery/javascript to do so.

For example, to add `opacity` and `color` css properties:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table.parent > tbody > tr > td:first-child').each(function(){

  if ($(this).has('table.nested').length == 0){
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.5');  
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table parent">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TEXTA</td>
      <td>TEXTB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Has nested table below
        <table class="table nested">
          <thead>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>ABC</td>
              <td>PQR</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>TEXTC</td>
    <td>TEXTD</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you suggest me an alternative solution ?  Take the case of opacity. I want to add 0.7 opacity to only TEAXTA and TEXTC . I don't want the table to get this style. How do I do it?

Comment: i've just edited my answer and included a jquery code that solves the problem.

Comment: This is a good solution ! If I just want to exclude the table content and also color the "Has nested table below" text as red too , would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just give some class to TEXTA & TEXTB
for example:
(html)

```
<td class="red-color-text">TEXTA</td>
<td class="red-color-text">TEXTB</td>
```

(css)

.red-color-text{color: red;}

Comment: I feel like if OP wanted to do a solution like this he would have put it in. I am sure they are looking for a more CSS based solution.